# How to check if a string contains multiple letters at specific indexes

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I new some help with checking the string if it contains multiple specific letters at a certain indexes.

```sh
if [[ $letter == "${line:$index:1}" ]]; then
   loop_string $cnt $word $line
fi
```

The reason I need this is because I loop through a file and check for strings matching my parameters. (Don't mind the function at the middle)

So if a give a: -p 1 k switch that means it should contain letter k at index 1,
the problem is if a give multiple -p parameters ex. -p 1 k -p 2 s

Any advice would be helpful :D

Example: if I run a script with swithes: -p 0 b -p 2 r ... it should loop through a file looking for strings matching the parameters, it this case word that have given letters at given indexes

So if I run ./script.sh -p 0 b -p 2 r bird
it searches through permutations of the word bird in a file and echos if the word matches the parameters

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You are going to have to use a `for` loop to do this in plain Bash. And you probably want to use `getopt` to parse parameters easily.

Comment: I use getopt, i thought about for loop but it would take to much time and I just wondered if there's an easier method

Comment: Why do you think it would take  "too much time"?

Answer (score 0):

This works in bash (although not necessarily if you're searching for special characters, in which case you'd have to do some more magic around escaping):

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
        case $1 in
            -p )        shift
                        let index=$1-1
                        shift
                        findme=$1
                        egrep ^.{$index}[$findme] /path/to/my/file.txt
                        ;;
            * )         echo "I don't unerstand"
                        exit 1
        esac
        shift
done
```

$1 is the first argument to your command. `shift` pops that off the stack. See [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php) for a good intro to bash positional parameters.